# How to do variable interpolation on domain property in Grails?

Tags: variables, grails, dns

I am new to Grails and have been looking into doing variable interpolation on a domain property which I am calling from a service.

My Domain looks like this:

```
class MonthlyResult {

FilterType type
String typeId
Integer year
Integer january = 0
Integer february = 0
Integer march = 0
Integer april = 0
Integer may = 0
Integer june = 0
Integer july = 0
Integer august = 0
Integer september = 0
Integer october = 0
Integer november = 0
Integer december = 0
```

And I am trying to do this on my MonthlyResult monthlyResult:
monthlyResult.${monthName}
where monthName is a String with the name of the month that I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As simple as

```
String monthName = 'january'
assert 42 == new MonthlyResult( january:42 )[ monthName ]
```

Also, I'd rather use a `map` in such domain class, keyed by some enum values:

```
class MonthlyResult {

  Enum Month { january, february, .... }

  Map<Month,Integer> months 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add double quotes:

```
def monthName = 'january'
def monthlyResult = new MonthlyResult​()
println monthlyResult."​${monthName}​​"​
```

output:

```
0
```